# run psql query in bash

Tags: bash, connection, psql

I am new in bash and psql, I want to write a bash code that login a server the connect to psql database do a select query and then return the output. the set up I have as follow.

server named dbs, it has psql install and running. database name = dname, user= tester passwrod = 1234
in the database there is table called node_info it has 3 colons ip, mac, connection_time.
I want to run following query
select  ip, connection_time from node_info where ip=10.10.10.2;

Any tips how to write a shell script to do this remotely?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Did you try running psql and failed?

Answer (score 0):

If you have properly set your "pg_hba.conf" configuration file to achieve remote connections, you may try the following:

```
psql -U tester -h remoteip -p remoteport -d dname -W -c "select ip, connection_time from node_info where ip='10.10.10.2'"
```

Comment: Thank you for your replyis that pg_hba.conf file on my local machine or on the server?

Comment: Another question
if your commend is running on my local machine, do I need to have any setup on my local machine first to be able to run that script? like do I need to have psql install on my Mac first?

Comment: HI dgsleeps it is works now, I the problem I had was I didnt have psql install ed on my local machine