# Run postgres query from another server, in bash

Tags: bash, psql

I have a Ubuntu server that processes documents and another that have the database (postgresql 9.3).

I ran `psql -?` to understand how to connect to another DB and the final command would be:

```
psql -U postgres -W -h 1.2.3.4 -d testdb -p 5432
```

It works, but I must type the password after the command is issued.

I was trying to adapt this command in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -U postgres -W mypassword -h 1.2.3.4 -d testdb -p 5432 << EOF
select * from mytable;
\q
EOF
```

Needless to say this is not the right command.
Also, the password does not get recognized as a password, reporting the error:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "mypassword" ignored
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

In another server, where the script runs on the local DB, my working script is:

```
su - postgres -c "psql myDatabase" << EOF
select * from "myOtherTable";
\q
EOF
```

The question is simple, how can I write the right command for bash, to connect to another database with user/password and issue commands?

A link I tried, but password seems to not be set:
[run psql query in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688765/run-psql-query-in-bash)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
PGPASSWORD=yourpass psql -U postgres -W -h 1.2.3.4 -d testdb -p 5432
```

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-envars.html

or ~/.pgpass  file https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: good links! thanks i check them out and when working will mark your answer (:

Comment: At first it kept asking for the password, then it just stopped. Test server rebooted, script ran and worked!

I tried the .pgpass solution. creating this file in the root folder, permissions to 0600 and the command in the script is `psql -U postgres -h 1.2.3.4 -d dbname << eof [...] \q eof`